# How do you test out a VLAN interface?

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, vmware, vlan, dmz

The assignment for my internship was to learn how to configure VLAN for any given interface and then implement it. As of now I've been able to setup the interface but I have no idea how to test it.

The idea I had was:

1. Setup two ubuntu servers A and B on VMWARE or AWS,
2. Configure the VLAN say ens33.10 interface on server A
3. Set a bridge, say br0, that is linked to VLAN interface ens33.10
4. link server B to the bridge br0

Another idea was to setup a DMZ

So what I need to know is:

1. If the idea is even possible, if yes how does one do it.
2. If there's another easy way to test it out

Comment: Vlan on AWS - it means VPC, so you want to setup virtual system in VPC?